# searching in datagridview and filtering it

Tags: c#, datagridview

i have a question regarding with this code,  i use a bindingsource to show the data and this code only select the row when im searching in datagridview. i want to know how can i filter the data im searching.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string searchValue = textBox1.Text;

         dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;

         try
         {
             foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
             {
                 if (row.Cells[2].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))
                 {

                     row.Selected = true;
                     break;

                 }
             }
         }
         catch (Exception exc)
         {
             MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
         }
    }
```

Comment: You want to display only the filtered rows?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel yes :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you want to display only the filtered rows use `BindingSource.Filter` property.
Here is a good sample in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter.aspx)

```
bindingSource.Filter = "columnname = 'value'";

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string searchValue = textBox1.Text;

     dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
     bindingSource.Filter = string.Format("{0} = '{1}'","YourColumnName", searchValue );
     //here you can do selection if you need
}
```

---

To remove filter use the following

```
bindingSource.RemoveFilter();
```

or

```
bindingSource.Filter = null;
```

Comment: thanks with the code :) it work on mine. i highly appreciate it.

Comment: oh i forgot to ask, how will i refresh the datagridview after im done with the searching?

Comment: What do you mean by refresh?

Comment: after i've done with the searching, i want to show again the whole data in the datagridview so that if i want to search again i can choose other data to filter, is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Without changing that much your code, you could set the `row.Visible` property to `false` instead of just changing `row.Selected`. Anyway, the answer above is more performant and clean, you should try that.