# Anyone know how to search through a DataGridView using a text box?

Tags: visual-studio, datagridview

Basically I have my database linked up to my DataGridView and inside that DataGridView I have Authors, Books, Genres etc. I can search through it using dropdown boxes but I would like to do it using a text box. Anyone know how to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `BindingSource` to bind the data,

1. Check the answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18253624/searching-in-datagridview-and-filtering-it) SO question for filtered display of rows.
2. Check this [MSDN Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/12adc682-b477-4bf5-8864-0051a208947a/searching-for-specific-text-data-in-the-datagridview-control?forum=winformsdatacontrols) answer for searching specific text.

Answer (score 0):

You can try filtering data through SQL statements before binding them to your datagridview :)