# Optimize binded DataGridView search feature

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

*Hi everyone*,

I've got my code running perfectly fine, but it looks nasty. Its purpose is to search and display workers from my database that match search criteria. I've got a `DataGridView` on my form filled with workers databinded from my database. After I press `Search` button I only want to display the list of workers matching the criteria from `TextBoxes/ComboBoxes`. If they're empty it's displaying a full list once again.

---

**Search feature on form:**

[image: Search feature]

**Code:**

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FillList();
    List<Worker> list = new List<Worker>();
    bool match = false;

    foreach (var worker in workerBindingSource)
    {
        if (txtName.Text.Length > 0 && !((Worker)worker).Name.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(txtName.Text.ToLowerInvariant()))
        {
            match = false;
            continue;
        }
        else
            match = true;

        if (txtLastName.Text.Length > 0 && !((Worker)worker).LastName.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(txtLastName.Text.ToLowerInvariant()))
        {
            match = false;
            continue;
        }
        else
            match = true;

        if (txtOIB.Text.Length > 0 && !((Worker)worker).OIB.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(txtOIB.Text.ToLowerInvariant()))
        {
            match = false;
            continue;
        }
        else
            match = true;

        if (txtLocation.Text.Length > 0 && !((Worker)worker).Location.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(txtLocation.Text.ToLowerInvariant()))
        {
            match = false;
            continue;
        }
        else
            match = true;

        if (txtAddress.Text.Length > 0 && !((Worker)worker).Address.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(txtAddress.Text.ToLowerInvariant()))
        {
            match = false;
            continue;
        }
        else
            match = true;

        if (txtPhoneNumber.Text.Length > 0 && !((Worker)worker).PhoneNumber.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(txtPhoneNumber.Text.ToLowerInvariant()))
        {
            match = false;
            continue;
        }
        else
            match = true;

        if (!cboProfessionalQualification.SelectedValue.ToString().Equals("Empty") && !((Worker)worker).ProfessionalQualification.ToString().ToLowerInvariant().Contains(cboProfessionalQualification.SelectedValue.ToString().ToLowerInvariant()))
        {
            match = false;
            continue;
        }
        else
            match = true;

        if (!cboDegree.SelectedValue.ToString().Equals("Empty") && !((Worker)worker).Degree.ToString().ToLowerInvariant().Equals(cboDegree.SelectedValue.ToString().ToLowerInvariant()))
        {
            match = false;
            continue;
        }
        else
            match = true;

        if (match)
        {
            list.Add(WorkerDAO.ReadWorker(((Worker)worker).ID));
        }
    }

    SortableBindingList<Worker> sortableList = new SortableBindingList<Worker>(list);
    workerBindingSource.DataSource = sortableList;
}
```

---

Everything in code with "txt" prefix is `TextBox` and everything with "cbo" prefix is `ComboBox`. `ComboBoxes` contain certain enums that user can pick. If `ComboBox` is displaying enum value *"Empty"* it means user picked nothing (same as zero length value of string). `SortableBindingList` is just for sorting purpose on column header click, nothing important in this case. `ReadWorker` method is returning a worker only if he's matching all searching values and he's then added to list I display on `DataGridView` after. `FillList` method is setting whole list of workers from database to `DataBindingSource`.

---

**ReadWorker method:**

```
public static Worker ReadWorker(int workerID)
{
    var worker = ReadEverything().Where(x => x.ID == workerID).FirstOrDefault();

    return worker;
}
```

---

Method `ReadEverything` returns list of all workers from database.

I'm looking for a LINQ solution (or any other better solution) to reduce my code drastically and make it more readable, but since I'm still pretty fresh to programming and LINQ I can't figure it out myself. So I wondered if you guys could help me a bit or at least point me at right direction.

***Thanks in advance!***

Comment: Does the `ReadEverything` hits database as `Select * from table` ? Why not just use `select * from table where id = workerid` ?

Comment: What is the *type of* `workerBindingSource`? Is it in fact a `System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource`?

Comment: If it is binding source you can use `BindingSoure.Filter` property to filter the list

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, that's a very good approach. Add that and an example as an answer and you got my vote!

Comment: @SriramSakthivel ReadEverything is using Stored Procedure to read from database.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud yes it is, class Worker is added as data source in DataGridView

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Added as answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your datagridview already has all the data from database, I'll suggest you not to go to database for search again, because you already have all the data. Just filter it in memory and show it.

If at all you need to hit database for some reason, there is no reason to get all the data from database and filter it in client side, just pass the "workerId" to stored procedure, let the SP add proper where condition and return the filtered data.

To implement in memory filtering using Binding Source:

```
bindingSource.Filter = "columnname = 'value'";

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string searchValue = textBox1.Text;

     dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
     bindingSource.Filter = string.Format("{0} = '{1}'","YourColumnName", searchValue );
     //here you can do selection if you need
}

To remove filter use the following

bindingSource.RemoveFilter();
//or
bindingSource.Filter = null;
```

Originally posted as answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18253624/searching-in-datagridview-and-filtering-it).

Comment: Yeah I've already checked that original answer before posting my question, but I'm trying to do it this way. I just wanted to optimize the code with linq if it's possible. =(

Comment: You have to understand one thing. Linq doesn't optimize anything, It makes code readable and easy, that's it. Neverthless "I love linq". But, In this scenario I recommend you to use `bindingSource.Filter` that is specifically designed for this purpose only. You need to generate query to filter the data, and that's it.

Comment: Ok thank you, I value explanations from more experienced programmers. I upvoted your answer and will try to do it this way. I'll wait for another answers and opinions for a while, if nothing shows up I'll accept your answer. Cheers!