# DataGridView Filter Data

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datagridview, datatable

So probably a newbie question but something I could not find on google a let say resanable example off.

So I have a DataTable that I created from some xml

The columns are like:

- key
- Description
- parent

This DataTable is bound to a gridview with a DataBinding

The filter form returns an array of keys(string)

Now I would like to display only keys that get returned from filter.

My code so far:

```
    List<string> listKeys = new List<string>(_keys);

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grdData.Rows)
    {
        string k = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        if (!listKeys.Contains(k))
        {
            CurrencyManager currencyManager1 = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[grdData.DataSource];
            currencyManager1.SuspendBinding();
            row.Visible = false;
            currencyManager1.ResumeBinding();
        }
        else
        {
            row.Visible = true;
            //listKeys.Remove(k);
        }
    }
```

The result I am getting is either always full grid or none.
And the code above is very slow(performance wise). Any faster way of doing this?

Comment: this is asp.net web forms ?

Comment: @mybirthname `DataGridView` is winforms control.

Comment: It is a WindowsForms project

Comment: See if [this helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23524008/optimize-binded-datagridview-search-feature)

Comment: Probably I'm mistaken but why not use DataSource property of the grid and just rebind it ? Why need to remove columns ? Just when filter the data put the correct dataTable in the DataSource