# Reduce the number of items in a listbox while user types

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

Is there a way to reduce or increase the number of items displayed in a listbox as a user types into a textbox.  Right now I am loading the items into a list.  Then I am loading the list into the listbox.  I know how to make the selected index change to the best match as the user types, but I like the idea of the number of items changing more.

Comment: You could try binding it, and changing the underlying list as the user types:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675067/binding-listbox-to-listobject

Comment: Use a [binding source and filter it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18253624/searching-in-datagridview-and-filtering-it/18253812#18253812)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're essentially going to create a temporary list and utilize your list that is full of every possible solution. Call the TextChange() event of the text box, then do a comparison to what the user is entering. Store the proper matches into the temp list, then adjust the list box accordingly.

Example code,

```
    private void textboxInput_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<String> temp = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < fullList.Count - 1; i++ )
        {
            if (fullList[i].Contains(textboxInput.Text))
                temp.Add(ls[i]);
        }

        listboxOutput.DataSource = temp;
    }
```

This is assuming your list is not massive. This could cause some lag if your list was huge and had to be itterated every key press.

Edit One: Changed `fullList.Capacity - 1` to `fullList.Count - 1` in the for-loop.

Edit Two: This solution is case sensitive.

Comment: running in debug mode I can see it adding items to the temp list, but for some odd reason the listProducts.DataSource = temp; is never called.

Comment: OhSnap! I made a small error, the .Capacity should be changed to .Count. It might not be iterating correctly using .Capacity.

Comment: Had to make one minor modification and covert both sides to lower, but it works perfectly.  Thank you.